# Programatically run a load test without having the app in VSTS source control

Tags: azure-devops, load-testing

We're using an on-prem VCS and CI pipeline, and don't have plans to switch to VSTS right now. However, I'd be very interested in running cloud-based load-tests against our app as part of our CI pipeline. In order to do this, I'd have to be able to programmatically upload the loadtest script and invoke it from VSTS.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you success running load test programmatically now?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, the workflow like this:

1.Create a valid loadtest file. You can use the load test file from an earlier run through Visual Studio for this.

2.Create a location to upload the file(s). This location is a drop folder on Azure Blob and is below referred to as "TestDrop".

3.Upload the loadtest file and any other files required for the run, this includes the webtest files, settings file, etc. to this location or "TestDrop".

4.Create a Test Run using the Testdrop from the previous step as all the files required for a run are now available at the drop location.

5.Start the run.

6.Once finished, download the results to your local machine. This will be a gzip file. Uncompress it to get the results file.

7.Use Visual Studio to view the downloaded results.

[image]

More information, you can refer to [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/integrate/api/load-test/overview) article, which contains samples.